# Cycle through array

Tags: java

Supposing I had an array with 4 elements, and I want to cycle through them until a certain condition is met, what would the best way I would have to do so? My idea would be something like:

```
ArrayList<Player> myList = new ArrayList<Player>();
myList.add(new Player("a"));
myList.add(new Player("b"));
myList.add(new Player("c"));

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    if(isGameOver)
         break;

     if(i == 2)
        i = 0;
}
```

But I thought that perhaps there was a more elegant solution...

Comment: At the very least you should use the `size()` of your list as the loop bound, rather than hard-coding 3.

Comment: Note that it's perfectly legal to write `for (int i = 0; !gameIsOver; i = (i+1)%myList.size())`.  (Or use one of the other loop forms listed below.)

Answer (score 3):

The condition that breaks the loop should be used in a `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (!isGameOver)
{
    // Do something here.

    i = (i + 1) % 3;
}
```

Here, `%` is the modulus operator; i.e. the remainder when dividing by 3.  This way, `i` is 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: Make sure to explain what `%` is for newbies.

Comment: Cheers :D I think this will do :)

Comment: I really must be missing something, considering this answer doesn't cycle through an Array or ArrayList.

Comment: I had assumed that the code that used the `ArrayList` was omitted.  I represent that with `// Do something here.`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I prefer:

```
while (!isGameOver) {
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

    }
}
```

Or use the `foreach` construct:

```
while (!isGameOver) {
    foreach(Player p : myList) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would do a infinite while loop instead...

```
int k=0;
int n=myList.size();
do {
  int i = k++ % n;
  // use i
while(!GameOver);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) {
    while(!isGameOver){
        for(Player p : myList){
            p.doSomething();
        }
    }

    while (otherGameStates){
    }

    while(paused...){
    }
}
```

This is on the assumption that you are doing this somewhere in your gameloop. The `while true` allows for the state to change (if you have multiple states in your game) allowing the game to go from `pause>run` to maybe `pause>menu>run` or `pause>menu>quit` or `gameover>gamerunning`. The first block is probably just enough for your needs.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

@rgettman's answer is great :)

I am just giving another alternative.  Choose whichever suite the logic or thought-process

```
mainProcessLoop:
while (!gameOver) { // or while(true), if you are sure 
                    // that the collection is never empty
  for (Player player: players) {
    // do whatever you need for player

    if (gameOver) {
        break mainProcessLoop;
    }
  }
}
```